# Why is predict in R taking Train data instead of Test data?

Tags: r, svm, prediction, train-test-split

I have trying to build a svm model using a linear kernel. I have divided my 100,000 records into train and test. 70000 in train and 30000 in test.

```
model<- ksvm(train$CASE_STATUS_1.0~train$DURATION+train$WAGE_RATE_OF_PAY_FROM_HOUR+train$HOURLY_WAGE+train$OCCUPATION,data=train,kernel="vanilladot")
```

When I am using the following code

```
tab<- table(pred,test$CASE_STATUS_1.0)
```

I am getting Error in table(pred, test$CASE_STATUS_1.0) : 
  all arguments must have the same length

I understand the error is due to difference in length. I am unable to understand why is predict taking train instead of test.

When I checked the length of pred, it is 70000 (training set)

```
> length(pred)
[1] 70000
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: How are you creating `pred`? `predict(model, newdata=test)` would be the "standard" way to get predictions for `test`. Also, your model formula should not repeat the data frame name when referencinig column names (that is, remove all instances of `train$` in the model formula).

Comment: Removing the dataframe name worked. Thank you!